# How to change the variables Qi's to Ri's in one or two steps

Tags: system-variables

I was wondering if there is a command in Mathematica to change all the following Qi's to Ri's? For example, change Q1 to R1, Q2 to R2, etc.

```
 Q1 a1 + Q2 a2 + Q3 a3 + Q4 a4 + Q5 a5 + Q6 a6 + Q7 a7 + Q8 a8 + 
 Q9 a9 + Q10 a10 + Q11 a11 + Q12 a12 + Q13 a13 + Q14 a14 + Q15 a15 + 
 Q16 a16 + Q17 a17 + Q18 a18 + Q19 a19 + Q20 a20 + Q21 a21 + Q22 a22 +
 Q23 a23 + Q24 a24 + Q25 a25 + Q26 a26 + Q27 a27 + Q28 a28 + 
 Q29 a29 + Q30 a30 + Q31 a31 + Q32 a32 + Q33 a33 + Q34 a34 + Q35 a35 +
 Q36 a36 + Q37 a37 + Q38 a38 + Q39 a39 + Q40 a40 + Q41 a41 + 
 Q42 a42 + Q43 a43 + Q44 a44
```

I could go through and change the Qi's by hand, but I think there should be a more efficient way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to handle the case where some of the `Qi` symbols already have a value assigned to them?

Comment: Thank you for this comment @Mr.Wizard . All the answers below have been helpful! Yes, the Qi's and Ri's will eventually have a value to them (for example, Q1 = 1/2, Q2 = 0, Q3 = 1, etc and the same with the Ri's but the symbols Ri may have different values from the Qi's). At the moment, I'm not sure what values they will be.

Comment: I added a method to my answer that should be useful in that case.

Comment: in the long run it saves a lot of work to generate expressions like yours programmatically, e.g. `Sum[Q[i] a[i], {i, 44}]`, then you can go back later and just have to change the `Q` in one place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe I would use:

```
expr = Q1 a1 + Q2 a2 + Q3 a3 + Q4 a4 + Q5 a5 + Q6 a6 + Q7 a7 + Q8 a8 +
    Q9 a9 + Q10 a10 + Q11 a11 + Q12 a12 + Q13 a13 + Q14 a14 + 
   Q15 a15 + Q16 a16 + Q17 a17 + Q18 a18 + Q19 a19 + Q20 a20 + 
   Q21 a21 + Q22 a22 + Q23 a23 + Q24 a24 + Q25 a25 + Q26 a26 + 
   Q27 a27 + Q28 a28 + Q29 a29 + Q30 a30 + Q31 a31 + Q32 a32 + 
   Q33 a33 + Q34 a34 + Q35 a35 + Q36 a36 + Q37 a37 + Q38 a38 + 
   Q39 a39 + Q40 a40 + Q41 a41 + Q42 a42 + Q43 a43 + Q44 a44;

expr /. S_Symbol :> Symbol @ StringReplace[SymbolName@S, "Q" -> "R"]
```

Or more restrictively:

```
rule = "Q" ~~ x : DigitCharacter .. :> "R" <> x;

expr /. S_Symbol :> Symbol @ StringReplace[SymbolName@S, rule]
```

I feel that operating *only* on Symbols is cleaner and safer than converting the entire expression to and from a String.

---

It is not clear to me if you need this, but if you want to do the replacement *after* (while) `Qi`'s are assigned values you can do it like this:

```
{Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10, Q11, Q12} = Range@12;

expr = Hold[Q1 a1 + Q2 a2 + Q3 a3 + Q4 a4 + Q5 a5 + Q6 a6 +
         Q7 a7 + Q8 a8 + Q9 a9 + Q10 a10 + Q11 a11 + Q12 a12];

expr /. S_Symbol :> 
  RuleCondition @ Symbol @ StringReplace[SymbolName@Unevaluated@S, "Q" -> "R"]
```

> ```
> Hold[R1 a1 + R2 a2 + R3 a3 + R4 a4 + R5 a5 + R6 a6 +
>     R7 a7 + R8 a8 + R9 a9 + R10 a10 + R11 a11 + R12 a12]
> ```

Answer (score 8):

```
xQ = Q1 a1 + Q2 a2 + Q3 a3 + Q4 a4 + Q5 a5 + Q6 a6 + Q7 a7 + Q8 a8 + 
   Q9 a9 + Q10 a10 + Q11 a11 + Q12 a12 + Q13 a13 + Q14 a14 + Q15 a15 +
    Q16 a16 + Q17 a17 + Q18 a18 + Q19 a19 + Q20 a20 + Q21 a21 + 
   Q22 a22 + Q23 a23 + Q24 a24 + Q25 a25 + Q26 a26 + Q27 a27 + 
   Q28 a28 + Q29 a29 + Q30 a30 + Q31 a31 + Q32 a32 + Q33 a33 + 
   Q34 a34 + Q35 a35 + Q36 a36 + Q37 a37 + Q38 a38 + Q39 a39 + 
   Q40 a40 + Q41 a41 + Q42 a42 + Q43 a43 + Q44 a44;

xR = ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString@xQ, "Q" -> "R"]
```

Comment: Thank you belisarius! We have so many options...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Find and Replace command: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on the Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on a PC.

Comment: (+1) Although I also liked the string replacement answers, I can't imagine a case where this answer would _not_ be my first choice.

Comment: @Jens perhaps I'm missing something but how do you change all the `Qi` symbols without *also* replacing all the instances of the letter `Q` everywhere?

Comment: No need to use "Replace all" @Mr.Wizard just "Find and Replace"  For code of this size putting it on a separate .nb would isolate it if you wanted to use "Replace All" too.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this programmatically by converting the expression to strings, replacing `Q`s with `R`s and then converting it back to an expression. For example:

```
expr := Q1 a1 + Q2 a2 + Q3 a3 + Q4 a4 + Q5 a5 + Q6 a6 + Q7 a7 + 
  Q8 a8 + Q9 a9 + Q10 a10 + Q11 a11 + Q12 a12 + Q13 a13 + Q14 a14 + 
  Q15 a15 + Q16 a16 + Q17 a17 + Q18 a18 + Q19 a19 + Q20 a20 + 
  Q21 a21 + Q22 a22 + Q23 a23 + Q24 a24 + Q25 a25 + Q26 a26 + 
  Q27 a27 + Q28 a28 + Q29 a29 + Q30 a30 + Q31 a31 + Q32 a32 + 
  Q33 a33 + Q34 a34 + Q35 a35 + Q36 a36 + Q37 a37 + Q38 a38 + 
  Q39 a39 + Q40 a40 + Q41 a41 + Q42 a42 + Q43 a43 + Q44 a44;

expr2 := ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString@expr, "Q" ~~ x : DigitCharacter .. :> "R" ~~ x]]

expr2
(* a1 R1 + a10 R10 + a11 R11 + a12 R12 + a13 R13 + a14 R14 + a15 R15 + 
   a16 R16 + a17 R17 + a18 R18 + a19 R19 + a2 R2 + a20 R20 + a21 R21 + 
   a22 R22 + a23 R23 + a24 R24 + a25 R25 + a26 R26 + a27 R27 + a28 R28 +
   a29 R29 + a3 R3 + a30 R30 + a31 R31 + a32 R32 + a33 R33 + a34 R34 + 
   a35 R35 + a36 R36 + a37 R37 + a38 R38 + a39 R39 + a4 R4 + a40 R40 + 
   a41 R41 + a42 R42 + a43 R43 + a44 R44 + a5 R5 + a6 R6 + a7 R7 + 
   a8 R8 + a9 R9 *)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you R.M!