# Rule for specific symbols

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Given the examplary expression

```
expr = (x1 + x17 y2 )/Sqrt[y1 + xx3]
```

I want to apply a rule for every symbol-name starting with "x".

My solution

```
expr /. x_ :>f[x] /; And[Head[x] == Symbol, StringTake[ToString[x], 1] =="x"]
(* (f[x1] + y2 f[x17])/Sqrt[y1 + f[xx3]] *)
```

works but seems to be very complicated.

How could I simplify my approach? Thanks.

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8427/5478

Comment: Found a better one, let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: @Kuba: I disagree but accept closing. The links all show solutions using string operations in more or less complicated ways. I'm still wondering that MMA has no direct pattern-solution.

Comment: @kuba: where can I find the exact duplicate of my question?

Comment: Link in the top of this question. Linked question is the same except of what is the result of replacement, they have `->3` you have `:>f[x]`. The fact there isn't anything shorter there suggests that is the way to go. Unless you want to see an answer like: "no, go with linked topic".